# extra separator from pandas.to_csv function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that I am trying to split into a training and test set. 
I have made the following script to split the data as aforementioned:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

data_path = "/path_to_data/"

df = pd.read_csv(data_path+"product.dlm", header=0, delimiter="|")
ts =  df.shape 
# print "data dimension", ts
# print "product attributes \n", train.columns.values 


#shuffle data set, and split to train and test set. 
new_train = df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))

indice_90_percent = int((ts[0]/100.0)* 90)


new_train[:indice_90_percent].to_csv('train_products.txt',header=True, sep="|")
new_train[indice_90_percent:].to_csv('test_products.txt',header=True, sep="|")
```

The original file looks like

```
label1|label2|...|labeln
371658|description|...|"some value"
```

the file generated by to_csv()
has one extra column without a name at the begining, which looks like this

```
|label1|label2|...|labeln|
452488|422932|description|...|"some value"|
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I cannot repeat behavior with similar data records on python 3.4 and pandas 0.16.2 on Windows 7. There is no added column. Either something specific in the data, which causes bug in pandas, or some python2<>python3 issues

Comment: @EriksDobelis, I've actually added index=False and issue was resolved. It seems that pandas defaults to include the index in the generated csv file

Comment: You have extra column at the end, too. Assuming you copied correctly, I cannot repeat that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `index=False` solved the problem:

```
new_train[indice_90_percent:].to_csv('test_products.txt',header=True, sep="|", index=False)
```